# Djongo/MongoDB error while doing migration using django-allauth

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-allauth

Error i get

```
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT %(0)s AS "a" FROM "django_site" LIMIT 1
Params: (1,)
Version: 1.3.6
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: None
        Params: None
        Version: None
```

I am trying to login using social media authentication(all-auth). But this gives error while migrating all-auth fields into database. I am using mongodb.

Comment: I'd guess some SQL that Allauth uses is incompatible with Djongo. Which version of (a) Django (b) django-allauth are you using?

Comment: django- 4.1.7     django-allauth - 0.54.0